# Integral of $\sqrt{\cosh(x)}$ with respect to x

Tags: calculus, hypergeometric-function, hyperbolic-functions, elliptic-integrals

I am trying to obtain a solution for the integral
\begin{equation}
\int^{x}_{0} \sqrt{\cosh(x)} dx.  
\end{equation}

A CAS system yields an answer depending on an elliptic integral of the second kind without giving me the reference to find the elliptic integral in question.

If I instead write $\cosh(x)$ above as
\begin{equation}
\cosh(x) = \frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2} = \frac{e^{x}}{2}(1+e^{-2x}),
\end{equation}
I end up obtaining an answer in a CAS as dependent on a hypergeometric function, but again without a reference to find exactly where to look up what that function would be.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to solve that integral?  If one could further provide some references for my further education on these areas, that would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "$\int_{\color{blue}{?}}^{\color{red}{x}} \sqrt{\cosh(\color{red}{x})}\, {\rm d}{\color{red}{x}}$"?

Comment: That I am evaluating the integral in the upper limit only, I don't care about the lower bound.  Essentially I then want to then solve for the real and imaginary parts of that integral set to zero.

Comment: The notation $\int^{x} f(x)\, {\rm d}x$ is  ambiguous, if the lower limit is not important just set some number and change the integration variable $x$ to a different variable, for example: $\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{\cosh(t)}\, {\rm d}t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+sqrt%28cosh%28x%29%29) provides links to [EllipticE](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticE.html) and [Hypergeometric2F1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html).  Not sure how helpful they are for your purpose.

I don't think there's any “nice” way to express this integral.  I'd recommend evaluating it numerically.

Here's a Taylor series for $x$ near 0:

$$x + \frac{x^3}{12} - \frac{x^5}{480} + \frac{19 x^7}{40320} - \frac{559 x^9}{5806080} + \frac{2651 x^{11}}{116121600} - \frac{2368081x^{13}}{398529331200} + O(x^{14})$$

For larger $x$, the $e^x$ term will dominate the $e^{-x}$ term, and you can just approximate the integral as $\sqrt{2}e^{x/2}$.

Comment: $\sqrt{2}e^{x/2}$ would be the integrand I would integrate with respect to $x$ in this estimate, correct?

Comment: @Will_Phys4: No, the integrand is $\sqrt{\frac{e^x}{2}} = \frac{e^{x/2}}{\sqrt{2}}$.  Integrating it multiplies it by 2.

Comment: Sorry, I read that as everything under the integral, hence why I was confused about you saying it was the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit as @Dan, at least for small $x$, use
$$\sqrt{\cosh (x)}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{2^n \,(2n)!}\,a_n\,x^{2n}$$ the first $a_n$ being
$$\{1,1,19,559,29161,2368081,276580459,43947282079,\cdots\}$$ which correspond to sequence $A008990$ in $OEIS$  (use their absolute values).

Comment: Claude, would you have a good recommendation for a resource to build up one's knowledge of these slightly more obscure summations?  Thanks!

Comment: @Will_Phys4. In fact, it is quite simple : take the first terms of the series of $\cosh(x)$ : the $(2n)!$ is obvious; use the binomial expansion (this make the $(1)^?$ obious) and identify the pattern. Then, go to OEIS !! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int \sqrt{\cosh(x)}~ dx=\int \sqrt{2\cosh^2\left(\frac x2\right)-1} ~dx=\int \sqrt{2\sinh^2\left(\frac x2\right)+1} ~dx$$
Putting, $u=\dfrac{ix}{2}\implies du=\dfrac{i}{2}~dx$,
$$I=-2i\int \sqrt{1-2\sin^2 u}~du=-2i~E(u|2)+c=-2i E\left(\frac {ix}{2}\bigg| 2\right)+c$$ where $~c~$ in integrating constant.

---

**Note:** Here $E(\phi|k^2)$ is called the [incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind).

In trigonometric form,
$$E(\phi|k^2)=\int \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 \phi}~~d\phi $$

For more details about elliptic integral, you may visit the following links:

[Elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)
[Elliptic functions: Introduction course](https://users.mai.liu.se/vlatk48/teaching/lect2-agm.pdf)
[Elliptic Functions and Elliptic Integrals](https://www.pdfdrive.com/elliptic-functions-and-elliptic-integrals-e158364095.html) by Viktor Vasilʹevich Prasolov
[Handbook of Elliptic Integrals for Engineers and Physicists](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-52803-3) by Paul F. Byrd & Morris D. Friedman
[Elliptic Functions: An Elementary Text-Book for Students of Mathematics](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/31076/31076-pdf.pdf) by Arthur L. Baker

Comment: Thanks, I will check these out!